# Settings.py returning ModuleNotFound error on app that exists

Tags: python, django

I am relatively new to Django and trying to create a simple app to enable a user to signup and login

However when I try to runserver to test what I currently have I run into this error message:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'signup.app'
```

This is the structure of my project

> peerprogrammingplat

> --- peerprogrammingplat

> --- signup

this is my installed apps in my settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'signup.app.SignupConfig',
]
```

my views.py

```
from .models import *
def register(response):
    form = UserCreationForm()
    return render(response, "signup/register.html", {"form":form})
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('register/', signupv.register, name="register"),
]
```

Answer (score 1):

you give the value in name in your `ModelNameConfig`.
in your `apps.py` in your app, you ll have something as following.

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class SignUpConfig(AppConfig):
    name = "signup" # this name value is given in your settings.py in INSTALLED_APP list.
```

something link

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'signup',
]
```

Comment: Still getting an error message:

ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package